# VBA code to hide or unhide rows based on a cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

Heres my code, but its not really doing anything, I dont see anything wrong with it:

```
Private Sub PG1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If .Range("E50").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    ElseIf Range("E50").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

My intention is that when that specific cell in the previous row is set to "Passed" from the dropdown, then the below row would appear, if its a 'Failed" then it'll be hidden instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like your code has some typos in it.  You want something that is like this:

```
Sub PG1()

    If Range("E50").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E50").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

To have the row hide/unhide update as you change the sheet, put it in a `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("E50").Value = "Passed" Then
        Rows("51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E50").Value = "Failed" Then
        Rows("51:51").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

there was no typo.  "rows(51)" is valid.  but you don't need the "entirerow" modifier

```
rows(n).hidden=true    ; where n is an valid row number
```

to hide multiple rows

```
 range(rows(n1),rows(n2)).hidden=true ; will hide rows n1 though n2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub PG1()
    Range("$E$51").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("$E$50").Value = "Passed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question?