# How do I create a macro to show/hide rows based on a dropdown list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Tried to follow some advice based on a previous post ([VBA code to hide or unhide rows based on a cell value](https://superuser.com/questions/663441/vba-code-to-hide-or-unhide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value)) to create a macro so that I can show/hide certain rows based on a dropdown list. I'm pretty close to having it, but at least 1 part of my formula isn't working. Here's what I'm using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("D13").Value = "Unlimited" Then
         Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Unlimited" Then
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("D13").Value = "Limited" Then
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Limited" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Range("D13").Value = "Select one" Then
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Select one" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

With this formula, I'm looking to influences what rows are shown below the dropdown list selection based on what the user selects. Cell with dropdown list is D13. It has 3 possible values: Limited, unlimited & select one. Here's what Im aiming for:

- Select one: all rows from 77-82 are visible
- Limited: Row 77 is visible, rows 78-82 are hidden
- Unlimited: Row 77 is hidden, rows 78-82 are visible

The code I have above seems to work somewhat inconsistently: not sure if the functions I've set for each dropdown are overlapping each other unexpectedly? Right now my functions are working as expected only when you change from select one --> limited/unlimited, but I can't get them to continue working if you subsequently change to another selection.

Any help anyone has would be very appreciated!! Currently tearing my hair out a bit over this haha. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line in the code below handles the Worksheet_Change.  It makes sure only one cell was changed and that the cell was D13.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, Range("D13")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub

    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Select One" Then
        Rows("77:82").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Limited" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = True    

    ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Unlimited" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = False   

    End If

End Sub
```

Note that the code above must be copied into the **Worksheet** object for whatever Sheet your dropdown is on.

[image]

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help! Unfortunately entered in code exactly as above and no dice :( Nothing changes when I change the D13 dropdown. I would send you a screenshot if I could!

Comment: Make sure the code is in the right place.  It runs on a Worksheet_Change event, so the code has to be in the Sheet where your dropdown is.  Not in a Module.  Not in the ThisWorkbook object.

Comment: Aaand I'm an idiot haha, it worked- finally!! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Great!  Glad to help.  If you found this answer helpful, you could click on the check mark to accept it.  And the upward grey triangle too.  :-)

Comment: BTW, when I was testing this, it didn't work at first. I had the code in a Module and it took me a while to figure out it had to be in the Sheet. So don't worry about it, its an easy mistake to make.  :-)

Comment: I am on it! And thanks for reassuring me I'm not a total moron ;)

Answer (score -1):

*You can use this simple Macro to hide/unhide  the specific Rows.*

```
Private Sub Hide_Unhide()

  If Range("D13").Value = "Select One" Then
       Rows("77:82").EntireRow.Hidden = false
  End if

  If Range("D13").Value = "Limited" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = false
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = true    

  ElseIf Range("D13").Value = "Unlimited" Then
        Rows("77").EntireRow.Hidden = true
        Rows("78:82").EntireRow.Hidden = False   

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: hank you! Unfortunately unless I'm missing something I don't think this worked - same problem as before where you can't go between the dropdown items and have the hidden rows change. Unless maybe I need to add something so that the macro runs every time you change the dropdown?

Comment: @elliem, yes, you've got it right. You need the Sub to run on the Worksheet_Change event **and** you need to make sure the cell that was changed was actually your dropdown. See the answer below, or above, depending on how the page is sorted. :-)

Comment: it's simple,, @elliem make drop-down assign all 3 criterion and attach Cell D13 to it. Every time you select value from drop-down excel will reflect in Cell D13 and the Macro will work accordingly. Both answer comprises the same code line that matters. :-)

Comment: @Bandersnatch & Rajesh S I'm sorry just saw this! I'm going to try to do this now :) But I did already try your solution above Bandersnatch. Fingers crossed though, I will make this thing work!! lol